# Joining column preference in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

```
select *
from tableA ta
inner join tableB tb on tb.columnbid = ta.columnaid
```

When joining 2 tables, is the joining column preference important?

Should I use

```
on ta.columnaid = tb.columnbid
```

instead?

Comment: `on tb.columnbid=ta.columnaid` and `on ta.columnaid=tb.columnbid` are equivalent. No difference, just another way of writing the same thing. Some prefer the the first option, because it corresponds to human language: "join the row where its column matches ...". Others prefer the second option, because all conditions start with where you come from, i.e. what the joined row relates to.

Answer (score 0):

No, the order of the equation does not play any part in execution or optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

The equation **tb.columnbid=ta.columnaid** simply means that show only those rows where both of them are equal. So the order ***doesn't*** matter. You can write ta.columnaid=tb.columnbid and will find the same result.